# Javascript recursion for tree creation

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, tree, scope

i am trying to create funcion for creating decision tree with state of game in every node in game (doesnt matter what game). I wrote recursive function (DFS) like this:

```
function makeTree(anchor,count,player){
    var subTree=null;
    var nodes=[];
    if(player)var newPlayer=false;
    else var newPlayer=true;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
            if(anchor["state"][i][j]==0){
                var newState=anchor["state"];
                if(player)newState[i][j]=1;
                else newState[i][j]=2;
                var node={name:i+"_"+j, contents:[],state:newState, value:null, player:newPlayer};
                if(count>0){
                    var newCount=count-1;
                    subTree=makeTree(node,newCount,newPlayer);
                    node["contents"]=subTree;
                }
                nodes.push(node);
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

And with call:

```
var tree={};
var hrac=true;
var plocha=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
var state=plocha;
    tree={name: "root",
          contents:[], 
          state:state, 
          value:null, 
          player: hrac};
    tree["contents"]=makeTree(tree,3,hrac);
```

But the function change variables in different scope, so the output tree will be like this:

```
"root" - node - node - node
                     - node
                     - node
                     - node
                     - node
```

I cant figure out what is going on with variable `newState` in that function, because after finish the recursion the original variable `plocha` has the value of the latest `node["state"]`. Any suggestions what to do?

EDIT: Thanks to Bergi i realize that i need to do deep copy of array insted of make reference to it, so i make funcion for copy of array and now this works. Thank you Bergi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `state` property is an array, which is mutable. On every assignment, you change the one multidimensional array that is the `state` of *all* nodes. You'll want to make every `newState` a new array, instead of passing your `plocha` reference recursively through all functions:

```
 …
 var newState = anchor["state"].slice(); // create copy of the outer array
 newState[i] = newState[i].slice(); // copy of the row to be modified
 newState[i][j] = player ? 1 : 2;
 …
```